# How does postman generate Cookies and how would i Replicate it in my code

Tags: post, cookies, postman

My request on postman automatically generates a cookie called __cf_bm= which changes with every request and exporting the request as code leaves you with the last cookie which doesn't work. How is postman generating this cookie and how can i replicate it in my code?